# Columns to Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have a query returning a table which looks like:

```
Location | November | December | January | February | March | ... | October |
   CT        30         70         80         90       60             30
 etc.
```

and I'd like it to look like:

```
Location |   Month   | Value |
   CT       November    30
   CT       December    70
   CT       January     80
             ...
   CT       October     30
```

It looks like an unpivot, but I didn't pivot to get it into that form since the base table has the months as columns (the values are just sums of values grouped by location). I've seen plenty of rows-to-columns questions but I haven't found a good columns-to-rows answer, so I'm hoping someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use the `UNPIVOT` function. This transforms the values of your columns and turns it into rows:

```
select location, month, value
from <yourquery here>
unpivot
(
  value
  for month in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August,
                September, October, November, December)
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec474/2)

Comment: @user1883730 happy to help, if this is helpful, be sure to accept via the checkmark on the left.